# Appscript Triggers on pasting values

Tags: google-apps-script, triggers

I got this script working, but i want it to trigger, the moment i paste the values onto spreadsheet "raw Data", instead of manually running it.

```
function deleteColumns() {
  var sh1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("raw Data")
  sh1.deleteColumn(1)
  sh1.deleteColumn(3)
  sh1.deleteColumns(4,3)
  sh1.deleteColumns(8,7)

}
```

Comment: Welcome to [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Comment: See [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/13045193)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do that is to use an `onEdit(e)` [simple trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers), like this:

```
/**
* Simple trigger that runs each time the user hand edits the spreadsheet.
*
* @param {Object} e The onEdit() event object.
*/
function onEdit(e) {
  if (!e) {
    throw new Error(
      'Please do not run the onEdit(e) function in the script editor window. '
      + 'It runs automatically when you hand edit the spreadsheet. '
      + 'See https://stackoverflow.com/a/63851123/13045193.'
    );
  }
  if (e.range.getSheet().getName() === 'raw Data') {
    deleteColumns();
  }
}
```

The function will delete columns every time you manually modify the 'raw Data' tab. To do that only when certain types of events take place, use an "on change" [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable).

Comment: onEdit won't work , since ill have to do extra inputs after this step, meaning it will keep on deleting columns, does onChange happens only once even after extra inputs?

Comment: You may be better off by running the function from call the function through some other means, such as a [button](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus#clickable_images_and_drawings_in_google_sheets), a [custom menu item](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/menus), or a [sidebar](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs#custom_sidebars). Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74371266/edit) the question to include your exact requirements.

Comment: i guess a custom menu will do the trick. thanks for the help!